# Email address validation

Tags: marketing-cloud

I struggle with a high number of hard bounces when I send emails to inactive users. Most of them created an account with email addresses which don't exist in the domain.

I use validate email REST API within Marketing Cloud to reduce the number of hard bounces, but unfortunately this API doesn't resolve the issue with non existent email addresses.

Do you have any ideas how I can get know if the email adress exists in the domain before a sendout?

Comment: You could consider using a service like [this one from Informatica](https://www.informatica.com/products/data-quality/data-as-a-service/email-verification.html) which validates the email address directly with the domain

Comment: I have also heard good things about emailhippo https://tools.emailhippo.com/  - have not tried it myself.